# User reports a bug in datagrid - more entries get randomly highlighted

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

A user of my application has reported an issue with a datagrid in the application:

Sometimes, when he wants to select an entry, more entries are selected (not a continuous selection though, he sent a screenshot) - however, I could not reproduce this at all.

Here is the declaration of my datagird:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="mGlossaryGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding GlossaryItems}"   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  HeadersVisibility="None" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                          SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsReadOnly="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  SelectedCellsChanged="mGlossaryGrid_SelectedCellsChanged_1">



private void mGlossaryGrid_SelectedCellsChanged_1(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var cell = e.AddedCells.First();
            mGlossaryGrid.ScrollIntoView(cell.Item);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a clue what could be causing this bug?

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 0):

As a guess I would assume that they are being equality tested as duplicates and therefore since there is a data (or reference?) equality, they are being considered the same and being selected.  Check the data being selected for similarity and look for a trend.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the items in his screenshot and they are not data equal, a binding to a class with overriden Equals() is used and it checks for equality on all properties.